# Retrieve javascript comments in javascript, or, how do I parse js in js?

Tags: javascript, parsing, comments

I am looking for a way to access javascript comments from some (other) javascript code.
I plan on using this to display low level help information for elements on the page that call various js function without duplicating that information in multiple places.

mypage.html:

```
...
<script src="foo.js"></script>
...
<span onclick="foo(bar);">clickme</span>
<span onclick="showhelpfor('foo');>?</span>
...
```

foo.js:

```
/**
 * This function does foo.
 * Call it with bar.  Yadda yadda "groo".
 */
function foo(x)
{
    ...
}
```

I figure I can use getElementsByTagName to grab the script tag, then load the file with an AJAX request to get the plain text content of it.  However, then I'd need a way to parse the javascript in a reliable way (i.e. not a bunch of hacked together regexp's) that preserves the characters that simply eval'ing it would throw away.

I was thinking of simply putting the documentation after the function, in a js string, but that's awkward and I have a feeling getting doxygen to pick that up will be difficult.

```
function foo(x) { ... }
foo.comment = "\
This functions does foo.\
Call it with bar.  Yadda yadda \"groo\".\
";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a little parser that does not parse the complete JS language, but only matches string literals, single- and multi-line comments and functions of course.

There's a JS parser generator called [PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/) that could do this fairly easy. The grammar could look like this:

```
{
var functions = {};
var buffer = '';
}

start
  =  unit* {return functions;}

unit
  =  func
  /  string
  /  multi_line_comment
  /  single_line_comment
  /  any_char

func
  =  m:multi_line_comment spaces? "function" spaces id:identifier {functions[id] = m;}
  /  "function" spaces id:identifier                              {functions[id] = null;}

multi_line_comment
  =  "/*" 
     ( !{return buffer.match(/\*\//)} c:. {buffer += c;} )*               
     {
       var temp = buffer; 
       buffer = ''; 
       return "/*" + temp.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
     }

single_line_comment
  =  "//" [^\r\n]*

identifier
  =  a:([a-z] / [A-Z] / "_") b:([a-z] / [A-Z] / [0-9] /"_")* {return a + b.join("");}

spaces
  =  [ \t\r\n]+ {return "";}

string
  =  "\"" ("\\" . / [^"])* "\""
  /  "'" ("\\" . / [^'])* "'"

any_char
  =  .
```

When you parse the following source with the generated parser:

```
/**
 * This function does foo.
 * Call it with bar.  Yadda yadda "groo".
 */
function foo(x)
{
    ...
}

var s = " /* ... */ function notAFunction() {} ... ";

// function alsoNotAFunction() 
// { ... }

function withoutMultiLineComment() {
}

var t = ' /* ... */ function notAFunction() {} ... ';

/**
 * BAR!
 * Call it?
 */





            function doc_way_above(x, y, z) {
    ...
}

// function done(){};
```

the `start()` function of the parser returns the following map:

```
{
   "foo": "/** * This function does foo. * Call it with bar. Yadda yadda \"groo\". */",
   "withoutMultiLineComment": null,
   "doc_way_above": "/** * BAR! * Call it? */"
}
```

I realize there's some gaps to be filled (like `this.id = function() { ... }`), but after reading [the docs from PEG.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/documentation) a bit, that shouldn't be a big problem (assuming you know a little of parser generators). If it is a problem, post back and I'll add it to the grammar and explain a bit about what's happening in the grammar.

You can even [test the grammar](http://pegjs.majda.cz/online) posted above online!

Comment: eek, that's a bit more involved than I was hoping for, but it looks like it should do what I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a unique string identifier at the beginning of every comment, and then using that unique identifier you could easily craft a regex to extract the comment.