# How can I do a js script which I get all comments in script tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to log comments in script tags in an html document. How can i do that ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        //my comment
        var test = "some js";

        /* start of comment
        ...
        end of comment*/
        </script>
        <!-- This is a comment -->
        <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

For now, I have this snippet of code to get all html comments

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);

jQuery.noConflict();

$(function() {
$("*").contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 8;
}).each(function(i, e){
    console.log(e.nodeValue);
  });
});
```

will return : This is a comment

Comment: use regex to find the newline starting `//` for single line comments and `/*`[wild character]`*/` pattern for multiline comments

Comment: Checkout this question.  [Retrieve javascript comments in javascript, or, how do I parse js in js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4227802)