# Is there any way to get the comments from a JS method or function?

Tags: javascript, comments

Of course we can read the comments in JS a method or function by reading the code.
However, is there any way to output the comments programmatically, e.g.

```
showComments([className].[methodName])
```

or

```
showComments([functionName])
```

By analogy, in MatLab, we're able to write

```
help [methodName]
```

..which would print on-screen the first couple of lines of comments. Super useful quick way to have built-in documentation for the coder-users.

Comment: Not easily if you want it to be 100% reliable. You'd need an AST parser.

Comment: If you're looking for this kind of documentation, look into something like JS Doc. it's basically a consistent way of documenting functions and is generally displayed in a user-friendly format when using the function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227802/retrieve-javascript-comments-in-javascript-or-how-do-i-parse-js-in-js this may help